# Passing SQL statements to PHP server with POST

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, post

In my Java code I have something like this:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sql", "INSERT INTO 
`TABLE_NAME` ( `id` , ,`description`)VALUES (NULL , 'some text')"));
```

But when the string reaches the server, it  is like:

```
$sql = $_POST['sql'];
```

`$sql` contains:

```
INSERT INTO  `TABLE_NAME` ( `id` , ,`description`)VALUES (NULL ,
\'some text\')
```

The thing is I want to pass SQL statements to my PHP server and execute them on the server
like this:

```
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

I want to me able to send SQL statements to server and then parse the response. But the SQL statements I want are to be built in the Java application.

How should this be done?

is this protected enough ?

```
 if(isset($_GET['phpusername']) && ($_GET['phpusername'] == "user" ) )
 {  
if(isset($_GET['phppassword']) && ($_GET['phppassword'] == "pass" )) {
               `//do some execution of raw sql query`
         } }
```

Comment: This is a **BAAAAADDDD** idea.. Consider the case of someone figuring out your HTTP request structure and passing in `sql=DROP TABLE students;`. Never EVER pass around raw sql between client/server. Pass individual bits of data, e.g. an id value, and then build your queries on the server.

Comment: can give some links where should read more about how this should be done ? (without to read book of 500 pages)

Comment: Yeah MarcB is right. Please change your design **seriously**

Comment: HORRIBLE idea.  At least pass the SQL and parameters separately so that they can be intelligently handled by PHP using PDO or the like.

Comment: Not to mention the fact about using `mysql_`

Comment: *"is this protected enough"* - no, use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) at the very least. Switch to prepared statements, `MySQLi_` and better yet use PDO.

Comment: The top is called sql injection. It is widely documented - but make sure you're reading a recent guide (i.e. last couple of years)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You use(d) `mysql_real_escape_string()` on values, not on a string containing sql.

Comment: @jeroen I meant for this `if(isset($_GET['phpusername'])` etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, missed the edit...

Comment: @jeroen No problemo ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: escaping wouldn't help, because it's a complete sql statement. it'd be escaping required quotes, e.g. `select 'foo'` would become `select \'foo\'` and become useless.

Comment: @MarcB Then the OP should switch to PDO/prepared statements.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: How would that help? op would still be passing in a complete query and end up doing `drop table students;` the entire design should be scrapped and rebuild as a proper webservice.

Comment: @MarcB Yes I agree 100%, it should be totally rebuilt. I was going to edit my comment about that actually.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That is exactly my problem the select 'foo' become select \'foo\' and it is useless how to fix this ?

Comment: sql injection is not a problem , it wont be exposed publicly, I just want to make it work...

Comment: Any suggestion for solution ? I tried with this $sql=str_replace("\'","'",$sql1); But I guess there is something else that I am missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to construct queries on java side and can't avoid that, I would recommend you to send not the whole query line, but a pairs like table_name='mytable', id='12', description='blablabla'.

For example, you can use[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format or simple post, or anything you like. You can do that line of variables on java side, send it to php side, parse it there and make a query "of your dream" ;)